# Use function in loop over set of files in directory

Tags: r, tapply

I'm trying to do some data analysis as follows: I have about 100 subjects, each of whom have a file containing 40,000 lines of numbers. I also have an index file with 40,000 corresponding lines containing group number. I am trying to get the means of each group, for each subject. I can do this easily for one subject with tapply, like this:

`tapply(df$numbers, df$group, mean)`

I can also load in a data frame containing the filenames of each subject's data. What I'd like to do is create a for loop in which I can get the output of the above tapply function for each subject, probably by looping over the filenames and pulling in each one as a new data frame (maybe??). And ultimately I'll want to output this to a .csv with subject names as rows and group names as columns.

Right now I'm very stuck. Can anyone provide some insight?

EDIT: Here's my solution, provided by super helpful user jyr below, with some minor tweaking. One thing I wasn't clear about was that my legend (the file with the list of labels) is its own file, rather than a column in each data file. Also, tapply was being a jerk about argument length, so I had to do some extra data frame creation. Here's the final solution:

```
labels_L <-read.table("C:/Users/jakes/Desktop/HMAT-files/CIVET_HMAT_left.txt")
new_df<-c()
listfiles <- dir("C:/users/jakes/Desktop/HMAT-files/thickness/left")
for(f in listfiles){
        thick <-read.table(file.path("C:/users/jakes/Desktop/HMAT-files/thickness/left",f), header=FALSE)
    df = data.frame(labels_L, thick)
         new_line <- c(f, tapply(df$V1.1, df$V1, mean))
         new_df <- rbind(new_df, new_line)
 }
write.csv(new_df,"C:/users/jakes/Desktop/HMAT-thickness-L.csv")
```

Thank you so much for your help, this forum saved me countless hours!

Comment: Hi Jake! To make this question better and easier for everyone else to help you, it would be great if you gave us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, if you can put an example of the code that you've done that would also be great. If you can put the first part of your data `head(df)` that will give us some data input to work with. We'll be able to help you much better then :)

Comment: You need to give us some context on the data. One great way to do this is to give us the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative *but not big* sample if your data. This might be as simple as `head(dat,n=10)`, but make sure you have at least two of each "grouping" id.

Comment: @Jake Thank you for this! I recommend you edit your question and add this to the question itself. It's good to keep things together! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read file names with `dir` and then loop over them, read each file and do your tapply, create vector with name of file and results for each file and merge them with `rbind`. I hope that this is similar to what you wanted or at least it can push you in right direction.

```
new_df<-c()
list_of_files <- dir("your_folder_where_data_is")
for(f in list_of_files){
         df <- read.csv(file.path("your_folder_where_data_is",f))
         new_line <- c(f, tapply(df$V1.1, df$V1, mean))
         new_df <- rbind(new_df, new_line)
 }
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you! I'll give it a shot tomorrow morning and report back.

Comment: And it worked, with some minor tweaking! Will post the full answer in my original post. Thank you!!